# Transient Fault Handling, SQL Azure ,Repository and EF

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I am building a Windows Azure application using EF and Repository pattern .I have guarded all my get methods and savechanges method in my repository with TFAB. Will this suffice or will I have to individually surround all my database calls from the business layer with TFAB?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your own business requirements.  You're not really required to utilize TFAB even for saves - in fact, most of the times when something fails it usually fails for longer period of time then the 1-2 seconds within which TFAB usually retries actions.

So, do you want to fail faster and retry longer? Regardless of TFAB your code needs to be prepared for failures.  Are your reads as important as your writes?  Do you care if certain functionality in your apps really try hard to work instead of throwing an error screen?  If so, then you should wrap your reads as well.